# ERROR: "Add is not a member of system array" in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

```
    Private Sub FileButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FileButton1.Click
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Files.Items.Add(OpenFileDialog1.FileNames)
```

I am getting an error `Add is not a member of system Array`.
Is there something wrong with the code? the idea basically is to display filenames in a listbox and the number of files in a specific label.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, there is no `Add` method for arrays. You probably want a `List` instead of an array.

Comment: Is `Files` the name of your listbox? Try naming it something like `lstFiles` instead. (Also, there is no need to tag `VBA` in a .net question.

Comment: Changing the listbox name did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `Files` the name of your listbox? Try naming it something like `lstFiles` instead.